# Hybris backoffice: Unable to search for Type

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I created a custom type say, MyType. I configured it in backoffice and created an instance from Backoffice using create wizard. I am able to confirm successful creation from HMC. 
The problem is when I search for MyType in backoffice(simple as well as advanced search) I do not get any results.

Could someone please let me know where I could be going wrong.

Regards,
Farhan

Comment: Do you search the type or the instance of the type?

Comment: I search for instances of MyType.

Comment: If you go on `Types`, search for `MyType`, then click on `Search by type` (after the key icon). And you will find all the instances.

Comment: Hi Alain, I have configured MyType to appear as a node in backoffice explorer. I further configured create-wizard, list view, simple search and advanced search. When I perform a search - simple or advanced, I do not see the instance I just created.

Comment: I see, it would be easier to help you if you post the customized code you're using then.

Comment: are you able to find it in HMC?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to reset Backoffice configuration from Orchestrator?

Login to Backoffice -> Press F4 -> Click on [Y] icon in top right -> Reset Everything

Comment: Generally, this approach had worked for me in the past.

Answer (score -1):

After you have done the configuration, you must to update the database. You could do it with `ant update` or with the Hac